# Problema al extraer palabras de un documento .docx extracción incompleta

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy trabajando con el modulo `docx` de python y estoy tratando de anexar a una lista las palabras que contiene el documento, el problema que ocurre es que la lista no guarda las últimas palabras, este es el texto de prueba `Documento.docx`:

```
Hola esta es
Una prueba
```

Este es el código:

```
import docx

texto = []
nuevo = []
lista = [' ',".",",",":",";"]

document = docx.Document('Documento.docx')
palabra = ''

for parrafo in document.paragraphs:
    for letras in parrafo.text:
        if letras not in lista:
            palabra = palabra+letras
        else:
            texto.append(palabra)
            palabra=''


print(texto)
```

Y este es el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Que es lo que deberias obtener?

Comment: @eyllanesc, una lista con cada palabra del texto indicado es decir la lista deberia de ser asi `[Hola,esta,es,una,prueba]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te está devolviendo `esUna` porque entre el primer párrafo y el segundo no encuentra ninguno de los caracteres de tu lista `lista`, por lo que lo considera una misma palabra.

La última palabra no te está apareciendo puesto que detrás de ella no tienes ninguno de los caracteres de tu `lista`, por lo que al no encontrar ninguno, nunca entrará en el `else` del bucle y no incluye esa palabra en la lista `texto`. Prueba a poner un punto o un espacio por ejemplo después de la palabra `prueba` y verás como esta vez si que te aparece.

Te pongo otro código que te cogerá el párrafo y eliminará los caracteres que no quieras para luego separarlo en palabras:

```
import docx
import re

texto = []
document = docx.Document('Documento.docx')

for parrafo in document.paragraphs:
    # Aquí eliminas los caracteres que no quieres en el párrafo
    p = re.sub(r'[.,:;]', '', parrafo.text)
    # Aquí divides el párrafo en palabras y lo añades a la lista
    texto.extend(p.split())

print(texto)
```

Esto te devolvería `['Hola', 'esta', 'es', 'Una', 'prueba']`

No eliminaría las palabras duplicadas, si además quieres eso puedes hacer un `set(texto)`

**Modificación**

En el caso anterior si encuentra que en el word se ha incluido una palabra seguida de uno de los caracteres e inmediatamente después otra palabra (por un error al escribir o cualquier otro motivo), lo tomará como una sola palabra, por ejemplo `ayer,fuimos` pasaría a ser `ayerfuimos`. Para evitar esto, es mejor directamente dividir el párrafo en palabras partiendo por los caracteres:

```
for parrafo in document.paragraphs:
    texto.extend(re.split(r'[.,:; ]', parrafo.text))
```

Comment: gracias estaba pensando utilizar regex, pero aun no terrminaba de entender como hacerlo

Comment: Tal y como lo había puesto antes si hay algún error y no han puesto espacios por ejemplo detrás de una coma, te lo iba a interpretar como una misma palabra. Ahora lo he modificado y de divide en los caracteres especificados, evitando que pase eso.

Comment: gracias si no es mucho molestar podrias anexar el codigo anterior a tu respusta para que se quede como expediente